# Laravel 5.1 - How to access resource id in a Request authorize() method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a real estate application. When the user opens the edit form to edit one of his properties, the blade code would be:

```
{!! 
Form::model($property, 
[
   'method'=>'PATCH', 
   'route'=>'property.update', 
   $property->id
]) 
!!}
```

As you can see the ID of the property that is currently being edited is the last array element.

How can I access that ID inside the authorize() function for the Request?

```
class EditPropertyRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Property::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                         ->where('id', <<< HERE IS WHERE I NEED THE ID FROM THE FORM >>)
                         ->exists();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `public function authorize($id)`

Comment: Can i use this as an answer and accept? :D

Comment: Haha, yeah go, put the answer

Comment: Ahaha. Tnx. You forget to put the `$id` there. to catch the `id` you pass. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function authorize()
                         ^ //add $id here
{
    return Property::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                     ->where('id', <<< HERE IS WHERE I NEED THE ID FROM THE FORM >>)
                     ->exists();
}
```